# Aggregate Dependencies in a Multi-Module Maven Project

Tags: maven-2

I am trying to figure out how to aggregate my maven dependencies in a multi-module project.  For example, if I have:

```
root pom/project1
root pom/project2
```

and I run `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, I end up with the dependencies in:

```
root pom/project1/target/dependency
root pom/project2/target/dependency
```

What I really want is that if I run the mvn command in the root pom folder, all of the dependencies to be copied to `root pom/dependency`.  Is there a maven property that gets me the output directory of the root pom? (similar to `${project.build.directory}`)?  I realize that I can just copy all the dependency folders to the same place after the fact, but I was hoping for something a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to configure the dependency plugin to copy depdendencies to a particular location. This can be done by the `outputDirectory` configuration property.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>copy-dependencies</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${outputDir}</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

But if you trying to do this for distribution, I'd recommend you create an assembly using the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html)

The documentation says:

The Assembly Plugin for Maven 2.0 is primarily intended to allow users to aggregate the
project output along with its dependencies, modules, site documentation, and other files
into a single distributable archive.

Answer (score 1):

> What I really want is that if I run the mvn command in the root pom folder, all of the dependencies to be copied to root pom/dependency. Is there a maven property that gets me the output directory of the root pom? (similar to `${project.build.directory}`)?

No, because modules shouldn't actually be aware of that.

> I realize that I can just copy all the dependency folders to the same place after the fact, but I was hoping for something a little cleaner.

The Maven way would to use the [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and [a custom descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html). But if you're not familiar with the Maven Assembly Plugin and its descriptor format, it won't be easy.

A less clean but easier approach would be to configure the [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to copy the dependencies into the parent project using a relative path. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>../root_pom/target/dependency</outputDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But as I said, this introduces tight coupling between modules and the root project which is not good at all (and I wouldn't go further by including the goal invocation as part of the build, modules should remain independent and you should be able to build one module without "checkouting" the parent).

Comment: @Greg did you find a way to do this with assembly plugin ?

Comment: @herau I don't recall what I did at the time to solve this, but if I was doing it again with what I've learned in the past few years I would use the assembly plugin.  You'd just need to add a new maven module at the root level, you can just call it "assembly" or whatever you want.  You'd include all your other modules as dependencies in the assembly project's pom file and then your assembly descriptor would include something like:

<dependencySets>
  <dependencySet>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
   <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
 </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>

That should get you close.

Comment: ok @Greg, it will try it. Does the assembly module should be linked with the parent's module ?